# WebSEAL to WebSEAL junction

Tags: tivoli, eai, junction, webseal

1. I have created WebSEAL to WebSEAL junction (EAI authentication enabled). Facing certificate issues, while creating the junction, application page displays third party server error. Incorporated all root chain certificates.
2. Does WebSEAL to WebSEAL junction work fine with EAI authentication enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WebSEAL to WebSEAL junction should work fine with EAI authentication.